# How do I make a daily dataframe from a start and end date column using python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame that shows sales promotions that are running and their start and end dates.  I need to turn that one row of data into multiple rows of data equal to the days the promotion runs.

Below is a sample of what the current dataframe looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
sample_dict = {'start_date': ["2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-03-01"],
              'end_date': ["2021-01-31", "2022-01-31", "2023-03-31"],
              'promo_item_no': ["a12345", 'b12345', 'c12345'],
              'cannibalized': [1,0,1]}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict)
sample_df.loc[:, 'start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df.loc[:, 'start_date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
sample_df.loc[:, 'end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df.loc[:, 'end_date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Below is a sample of what I would want the data to look like:

```
sample_dict2 = {'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04',
               '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08',
               '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10', '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12',
               '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-16',
               '2021-01-17', '2021-01-18', '2021-01-19', '2021-01-20',
               '2021-01-21', '2021-01-22', '2021-01-23', '2021-01-24',
               '2021-01-25', '2021-01-26', '2021-01-27', '2021-01-28',
               '2021-01-29', '2021-01-30', '2021-01-31',
                         '2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03', '2022-01-04',
               '2022-01-05', '2022-01-06', '2022-01-07', '2022-01-08',
               '2022-01-09', '2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12',
               '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14', '2022-01-15', '2022-01-16',
               '2022-01-17', '2022-01-18', '2022-01-19', '2022-01-20',
               '2022-01-21', '2022-01-22', '2022-01-23', '2022-01-24',
               '2022-01-25', '2022-01-26', '2022-01-27', '2022-01-28',
               '2022-01-29', '2022-01-30', '2022-01-31',
                         '2023-03-01', '2023-03-02', '2023-03-03', '2023-03-04',
               '2023-03-05', '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-08',
               '2023-03-09', '2023-03-10', '2023-03-11', '2023-03-12',
               '2023-03-13', '2023-03-14', '2023-03-15', '2023-03-16',
               '2023-03-17', '2023-03-18', '2023-03-19', '2023-03-20',
               '2023-03-21', '2023-03-22', '2023-03-23', '2023-03-24',
               '2023-03-25', '2023-03-26', '2023-03-27', '2023-03-28',
               '2023-03-29', '2023-03-30', '2023-03-31'],
                'promo_item_no': ['a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345',
                                   'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345'
                                  , 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345',
                                   'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'a12345', 'b12345',
                                  'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345',
                                   'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345',
                                   'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345',
                                   'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'b12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345',
                                   'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345',
                                   'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345', 'c12345'],
               'cannibalized':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
sample_df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict2)
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **pandas.date_range()** to list the dates between your start and end date and add that list to your dataframe in a column called "dates".

Next, use **explode("dates")** to create a row for each element in the newly created list.

```
import pandas

sample_df["dates"] = [
    pd.date_range(start, end)
    for start, end in zip(sample_df["start_date"], sample_df["end_date"])
    ]

sample_df.explode('dates')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a column that lists all the relevant dates and then explode that column:

```
import numpy as np

one_day = np.timedelta64(1, "D")

sample_df["dates"] = [
    np.arange(start, end + one_day, one_day)
    for start, end in zip(sample_df["start_date"], sample_df["end_date"])
]

sample_df = sample_df.explode('dates')
```